# Saxon parser returns an error 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, tfs, saxon

I'm using Saxon parser to create a report in the TFS build definition. I'm using the command line task as follows: `java -jar "C:/Performance Tests/SaxonHE9-9-1-5J/saxon9he.jar" -s:"C:\Performance Tests\Script\results\Result.xml" -xsl:"C:\Performance Tests\JMeter\xslt\jm.xsl" -o:"C:\Performance Tests\Script\results\JMeterJunitReport.xml"`. I have installed java on agents (jre) and specified `JRE_HOME` and `Path` to Java in system variables.`java -version` command works fine on the agent. But when I try to run the task in TFS, I get the following error:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What could be the reason of such behavior? In a case with JMeter adding PATH to java to jmeter.bat helped. How to fix it with Saxon? I've tried to add `set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin";%PATH%` to `saxon9he.jar` file which doesn't help. Other files in the Saxon folder are .jar and some .txt documents which don't seem to be appropriate here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means that the operating system can't find the "java" command. This has nothing to do with Saxon - if the OS can't load Java, then Java can't load Saxon, so there is no way Saxon can be part of the problem or part of the solution. In other words, you're barking up the wrong tree.

If Windows can't find a program to execute (in this case Java), that's because the program isn't on the PATH that Windows searches to find it. You either need to fix the PATH to include the Java executable, or you need to use a full path name when invoking it.

Comment: Thank you  It is fixed by specifying the full path to java in TFS task